# PreparedStatement not executing with correct query

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, derby

Does placing a prepared statement inside a for loop with varying query strings somehow breaks it?

I have this:

```
if(btn.equals("Continue")){
                String[] vals1 = request.getParameterValues("Vals");
                String count = "";
                queryStr = AniModel.deleteQuery(vals1);
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
                int update = ps.executeUpdate();
                count = "" + update;

                    request.setAttribute("query",queryStr);
                    request.setAttribute("count",count);
                    RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("success4.jsp");
                    dispatch.forward(request, response);
            }
```

It takes several array elements in which it uses on the call of the DELETE query that i created:

```
public static String deleteQuery(String[] title){
    String qry="DELETE FROM AnimeDatabase WHERE ";
    for(int i=0;i < title.length;i++){
        if (i>0) qry += " OR "; 
        qry += "ANI_TITLE='" + title[i] + "'";
    }
    return qry;
}
```

It gets the array values from this:

```
<%



                String[] values = request.getParameterValues("cbg");
                int countme=0;
                int numb=1;
                for(int i=0;i < values.length;i++){
                    countme++;
                    numb=countme;

                %>
                <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="Vals" value="<%out.println(values[i]);%>"id="vs_<%=(numb)%>"><%=values[i]%></td></tr>
                <% 
                    }
            %>
```

It has the correct query input in the end but its just not executing the update on the database.

EDIT:
I wish to achieve that when i do execute the command, it will do the looping and execute the statements depending on how many values are there in the array until it ends.

Set it to `conn.setAutoCommit(false);` 
and place `conn.commit();` inside the Continue code block.
Still doesn't work.

Comment: Where are you committing?

Comment: You should be calling `conn.commit();` somewhere in your code to persist the changes to the database, unless you have called `setAutoCommit(true)` on the connection. If you're not calling `conn.commit();` and don't have autocommit turned on...that'll be your problem.

Comment: I dont know where to place the commit. Also, updated the code. It just doesn't execute the query.

Comment: You should **not** concatenate values into an SQL query, use prepared statements with parameters. This makes things easier and more readable **and** protects you against SQL injection.

Comment: @JonK The default for a JDBC connection is to be in auto-commit mode.

Comment: Run your Derby with `-Dderby.language.logStatementText=true`  (https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/ref/rrefproper43517.html) and look in your derby.log to find out what statements you're actually executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points not knowing what you actually wish to achieve:

1. If you want to generate a query to DELETE records can you not create a single query encompassing the criteria to execute it once?
2. Are you by any chance having an issue with transaction commit? Are you starting a transaction?
3. If your query is taking parameters I would prepare the SQL string and statement outside the loop and in the loop set the parameters before executing.
4. Also make sure you don't have any other queries or issues in environment around the code shown.

There is however nothing wrong with your logic and although I find pattern (3) a bit more fast from my experience I cannot see a direct issue with the code right now.

(however there are some other issues there like count being a string for example but it may be a naming issue. though the update would return a number so you are converting again to a string but not actually doing anything with the count var which in essence will contain only your last number of rows effected in a string format)

For option 1 (and your edit). There is room for optimisation:

```
String[] vals1 = request.getParameterValues("Vals");
int count = 0;
String sql = "DELETE FROM AnimeDatabase WHERE ";

for(int i=0; i < vals1.length; i++) {

    if (i>0) sql += " OR "; 
    sql += "ANI_TITLE='" + vals1 + "'";

}

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
int update = ps.executeUpdate();
count = update;
```

Comment: Edit my post for you

Comment: Updated my answer too

Comment: Its returning a cast error: Integer cant be cast to String. Fixed it by changing count back to String again. But it still doesn't execute the query.

Comment: The you have an issue elsewhere, either due to point (2) on my post. Also the cast issue is also worrying. executeUpdate returns an int so there should be no cast error! You should not need count to be a String! See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()

Comment: I did not use any transaction or commit, nor am i starting one. Your code works, but the only problem is it somehow doesn't process the query. If i really need to start a transaction to actually fix this please tell me more about it. **Also, the values from "vals" comes from a JSP Form that is hidden. FYI** I tried executing the output query from the code directly to the database and it works.

Comment: The sql query that is built then works. Good. Now you need to figure out if you have an issue with your code executing the query. I would recommend that you create a clean copy of your code in a new JSP and run it directly in there. A simple DELETE statement, no extra logic. Hopefully you will be able to figure out why your code is not working.